# Cycle through images

Tags: php, json, api

I'm using google images api to retrieve some info about images. The only problem is understanding of `start` param. Here is my main cycle:

```
// $num - necessary number of images to find
function doGoogle($query, $num) 
{

    // Search images until we have need number
    $i = $k = $n = 0;
    while(count($resultStorage) < $num)
    {
        $base_url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0';
        $url = $base_url;
        if ($i == 0)
            $url .= '&imgsz=large&q='.urlencode($query).'&start=00';
        else
            $url .= '&imgsz=large&q='.urlencode($query).'&start='.$k.$n;

        // Request the page from google's api
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        $json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $data = json_decode($json);

        echo '<div style="clear: both"></div>Page: <b>' . $i . '</b><br />Url: <b>' . $url . '</b><br />';

        // Cycle through the list of result images
        foreach($data->responseData->results as $v)
        {
            // If we already have neccessary number of images
            if (count($resultStorage) == $num) break;

            // Show it up
            echo "<div style='float: left'><a href='{$v->unescapedUrl}'><img src='{$v->tbUrl}' /></a></div>";
        }
        $i++;
        $k++;
        if ($k == 9) { $k = 0; $n++; }
    }
};
```

How to manipulate with `n` and `k`? Because sometimes it returns the same pictures (cycling).

You can find my example-code at page: http://95.134.128.173/image.uploader.php (Just click Do Search).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean when you press the N or K keys it goes forward and back.

If that is the case you will need to use JavaScript, if you don't mind them using Alt + N and Alt + K then you can use the accesskey="n" attribute on the (already existing?) html buttons for next and previous.

If not, then I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I am helping you please don't take that tone.